# Наследуемый класс c++, задача

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, методы

**Задача:**
На фабрике работают несколько групп рабочих, каждая группа имеет название. Надо написать программу, которая на входе получает количество групп, и поочередно название группы, количество рабочих в ней, поочередно имя фамилию и год рождения каждого. Программа должна вывести названия всех групп, в которых все рабочие родились после 1974 года. Если таких групп нет, то сообщение “Not found!”. В программе нужно использовать классы Group և Worker.

**Входные данные:**
3
A-01
3
Ivan Ivanov 1998
Petr Petrov 1950
Sergey Sergeev 1978
B-02
2
Aleksey Alekseev 1989
Semen Semenov 1992
C-03
2
Igor Igorev 2000
Egor Egorov 1997

**Результат:**
B-02
C-03

Учусь всего месяц, знаю пока очень мало, и вот что вышло... не могу сделать так, чтобы названия групп выводились в самом конце. Может нужен еще один массив? или я вообще не в ту степь...
P.S. не судите строго)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Group {
    protected:
        std::string group_name;
        
    public:
        Group() : group_name("") {}
        Group(std::string group) : group_name (group) {}
        
        void cinAndSetGroup() {std::cin >> group_name;}

        std::string getGroupName() {return group_name;}
        
};

class Worker : public Group {
    private:
        std::string worker_name;
        std::string worker_surname;
        int year_of_birth;
    public:
        Worker() : worker_name(""), worker_surname(""), year_of_birth(0) {}
        Worker(std::string group, std::string name, std::string sur, int year) :
            Group(group), worker_name(name), worker_surname(sur), year_of_birth(year) {}
            
        void cinAndSetWorker() {
            std::cin >> worker_name >> worker_surname >> year_of_birth;
        }
            
        int getYear() {return year_of_birth;}
                 
};

int main() {
    int N, x, count;    
    std::cin >> N;
    Group* g_arr = new Group[N];
    Worker* w_arr = new Worker[x];
    bool found;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        g_arr[i].cinAndSetGroup();
        std::cin >> x;
        count = 0;
        
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            w_arr[j].cinAndSetWorker();
            if (w_arr[j].getYear() > 1974) {
                count++;
            } 
        }
      if (count == x) {      // tut polnaya laja(( a esli vivesti za cikl, teryaetsya x
        found = true;
        std::cout << g_arr[i].getGroupName() << "\n";
      }  
    }

    if(!found){
        std::cout << "Not found!";
    }
    
    delete [] w_arr;
    delete [] g_arr;
}
```

Подправила немного, добавила дополнительный массив, вроде работает. Но код оставляет желать лучшего))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Group {
    protected:
        std::string group_name;
        
    public:
        Group() : group_name("") {}
        Group(std::string group) : group_name (group) {}
        
        void cinAndSetGroup() {std::cin >> group_name;}

        std::string getGroupName() {return group_name;}
        
};

class Worker : public Group {
    private:
        std::string worker_name;
        std::string worker_surname;
        int year_of_birth;
        
    public:
        Worker() : worker_name(""), worker_surname(""), year_of_birth(0) {}
        Worker(std::string group, std::string name, std::string sur, int year) :
            Group(group), worker_name(name), worker_surname(sur), year_of_birth(year) {}
            
        void cinAndSetWorker() {
            std::cin >> worker_name >> worker_surname >> year_of_birth;
        }
            
        int getYear() {return year_of_birth;}
          
};

int main() {
    int N, x, count, k = 0;    
    std::cin >> N;
    Group* g_arr = new Group[N];
    std::string* after1974 = new std::string[N];
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        g_arr[i].cinAndSetGroup();
        std::cin >> x;
        count = 0;
        
        Worker* w_arr = new Worker[x];
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            w_arr[j].cinAndSetWorker();
            if (w_arr[j].getYear() > 1974) {
                count++;
            } 
        }
        
        if (count == x) {
            found = true;
            after1974[k] = g_arr[i].getGroupName();
            k++;
        } 
        
        delete [] w_arr;
    }

    if(!found){
        std::cout << "Not found!";
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            std::cout << after1974[i] << "\n";
        }
    }
    
    delete [] after1974;   
    delete [] g_arr;

}
```

**Updated**

Согласна с комментарием EOF, наследование не логично... Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать массив рабочих в классе Group, но сохранить при этом класс Worker (по условию должны использоваться эти два класса).

Нахимичила, но толку ноль...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Worker {
    protected:
        std::string worker_name;
        std::string worker_surname;
        int year_of_birth;
        
    public:
        Worker() : worker_name(""), worker_surname(""), year_of_birth(0) {}
 
        void cinAndSetWorker() {
            std::cin >> worker_name >> worker_surname >> year_of_birth;
        }
            
        int getYear() {return year_of_birth;}
          
};

class Group {
    protected:
        std::string group_name;
        int arr_size;
        Worker* workers_arr;
        
    public:
        Group() : group_name(""), arr_size(0), workers_arr(new Worker[arr_size]) {} 

        void cinAndSetGroup() {     //вводим название группы, количество рабочих и самих рабочих
            std::cin >> group_name >> arr_size;
            for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i) {
                workers_arr[i].cinAndSetWorker();
            }
        }

        std::string getGroupName() {return group_name;}

        bool all_1974Plus() {       //так хочу проверить, что все в группе родились после 74
          int i;
            for(i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
              if (workers_arr[i].getYear() > 1974) {
                continue;
              }
            }
            return i == arr_size; //если дошли до конца массива, то все 74+
        }

};



int main() {
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;          //количество групп
    bool found = false;
    Group* g_arr = new Group[N]; 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {      
        g_arr[i].cinAndSetGroup(); //создаем группы с рабочими
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {      
        if (g_arr[i].all_1974Plus()) {  // проверяем группы на соответствие 74+, если да выводим название
          std::cout << g_arr[i].getGroupName();
          found=true;
        }
    }  
           
    if(!found){                     //если не вывели ничего, то...
        std::cout << "Not found!";
    }

    delete [] g_arr;

}
```

Comment: По идее здесь не должно быть наследования. Группа не является Рабочим. Группа состоит из Рабочих.

Comment: Тем более в Вашем коде Рабочий является производным классом то Группы.

Comment: Просто задание такое, проходили наследуемые классы, согласна, что задача корявая (и мое решение тоже)), но вот что задали, то задали... надо использовать эти два класса

Comment: @EOF попробовала последовать совету, но ничего не выходит((
не могу отправить код в комментарии, попробую обновить вопрос...
посмотрите плиз в чем проблема (если конечно не во всем))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка первая, не выделили память для группы.

```
Group() : group_name(""), arr_size(0), workers_arr(new Worker[arr_size]) {}
```

Здесь выделено очень мало, так как `arr_size = 0`.

Выделять нужно попозже в `cinAndSetGroup`.

```
Group() : group_name(""), arr_size(0), workers_arr(nullptr) {} 

void cinAndSetGroup() {     //вводим название группы, количество рабочих и самих рабочих
        std::cin >> group_name >> arr_size;
        workers_arr = new Worker[arr_size];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i) {
            workers_arr[i].cinAndSetWorker();
        }
    }
```

Ошибка вторая. Вы игнорируете рабочих с <= 1974. Команда `continue` прощает тех кто > 1974. Короче пропускаете всех.

При первом попавшемся старике вы должны вернуть false.

```
    bool all_1974Plus() {       //так хочу проверить, что все в группе родились после 74
      int i;
        for(i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
          if (workers_arr[i].getYear() <= 1974) {
            return false;
          }
        }
        return true ; //если дошли до конца массива, то все 74+
    }
```

И выводить ответ не забывая перевод строки :

```
std::cout << g_arr[i].getGroupName()<<std::endl;
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Над конструктором повозилась и ни в какую... впервые создаю массив в классе, спасибо за помощь!! Про nullptr в жизни не забуду)) А с функцией all_1974Plus и выводом разобралась до этого сама)))